# How to add a tracking code in the head Bigcommerce?

Tags: api, web-applications, bigcommerce

I need the javascript tracking code to appear before the closing  tag after the app installation
Is there any way to add a custom js code via API or something

Answer (score 0):

To add tracking code to the head you need to edit the Panels/HTMLHead.html file.
To edit this file go to

```
{store_url}/admin/designmode.php?ToDo=editFile&File=Panels/HTMLHead.html&f=a
```

Hope that helps